# Bash doesn't source file unless manually started

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bashrc

bash won't source files from an login terminal unless I manually run bash from a terminal, I have bash (and not sh or dash). When I source a file, it returs errors (like "syntax error near unexpected " ) unless I don't run *$ bash* before source

```
$echo $TERM
screen-256color

$echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$shopt login_shell
login_shell     on
```

Error:

```
$source  ./shrc
-bash: ./shrc: line 105: syntax error near unexpected token `('

$bash 
$source ./shrc <-- now it works
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

When I run bash, I enter in the non_login shell, and it works. Why login shell is unable to source file?

**UPDATE 2**

```
$echo $0
-bash

$bash
$echo $0
bash
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
  else
        echo;
        echo "The SPEC environment variable is not set! Please source the shrc and try again."
        echo;
    fi
  }

  ogo() {   <----- LINE 105
      SHRC_NO_GO=0
      TOP=$SPEC
      if [ "x$TOP" != "x" ]; then
          if [ "x$1" = "x--help" -o "x$1" = "x-h" ]; then
```

It's a file from SPEC2006 benchmarks (is a well-know program, it is not my code)
My assumptions is that it's correct.
(infact, on non-login shell, it works)

Answer (score 0):

`$SHELL` stores your default shell, not your current shell. Try `echo $0` instead:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo $0
dash
```

Comment: it returns:  -bash

Comment: @cento: Can you show the line 105, too?

Comment: @chroba update 3, added with the code line 105